# BIOS freezes when trying to boot from Ubuntu live usb but works with arch

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

Same as the title but also,when I flash the ubuntu iso directly to the hard disk,strangely it works and the hard disk works like a live usb,
I have tried installing many older versions(7.04 ,16.10,18.10) but its of no use

64 bit pc(and image)
Using etcher on arch to flash ISO
Also used dd
Single boot

Hardware:

- Core2duo e6400
- Intel g41 chipset
- Esonic motherboard(10 year old machine,don't really remember the exact model)
- 4gb ram
- 120gb SSD, 1TB HDD

P.S.: I have BIOS not UEFI

Comment: Update BIOS or UEFI. Edit the question and post hardware specifications.

Comment: Also please provide specific versions (Ubuntu releases are *year.month* in format, an extra point is used for some releases to show update level, eg. 18.04.5 is the latest 2018-April release).  Any release from 2007 (7.0x) or 2016 (16.0x) are EOL & off-topic here.  The UbuntU ISOs have changed in recent releases, so have you tried a simple `dd` or other tool).

Comment: Added info about hardware and versions, I got the old versions from old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/ and have used the exact version names given there,haven't tried using dd will update info if it works.

Comment: Seeing that the hard disk works like a live usb,is it possible to make that hard disk a persistent "usb"

Comment: Unable to update bios,I don't think they are sending more updates for my bios,also can't seem to find esonic's website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so turns out my bios is way too outdated for proper usb boot, the only guaranteed way is to connect another ssd(or hdd) and flash ubuntu there using gnome disks or rufus/etcher(if on windows) and boot from that new hard drive through bios and follow the usb install process.

Comment: If you have at least a DVD reader you can use a DVD directly. If only a CD-ROM then you can use PLoP in a CD along with a USB.

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating installation media using "gnome-disks".
(Or if have Windows PC, u can use Rufus (select DD method.))

-> Install gnome-disks in our Linux distro.

-> Plug in our USB media.
-> Select USB media and click to "Restore Disk from Image"
-> Select Ubuntu .iso file

-> Reboot and try boot PC.

-> If you see GRUB menu, select "Ubuntu".

I detected some computers stuck at black screen with blinking white cursor like this:
[image: Ubuntu boot can stuck at here few minutes in CSM mode]

Do not worry, when u wait few minutes (i waited 10 minutes in a old PC), finally i see Ubuntu brandmark and booted successfully.

Comment: Didn't work,still the problem persists, can't get past logo screen

Comment: Also,the pc freezes before grub appears